# Como solucionar el (Uncaught Exception: FPDF error) al intentar generar PDF con PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Error al intentar crear un archivo PDF con PHP y la libreria FPDF

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already
>   been output, can't send PDF file (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paginaoctago\temp\lev_6\ord_com.php:68) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paginaoctago\temp\lev_6\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace:
>   0 C:\xampp\htdocs\paginaoctago\temp\lev_6\fpdf\fpdf.php(1052): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paginaoctago\temp\lev_6\fpdf\fpdf.php(999):
>   FPDF->_checkoutput() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paginaoctago\temp\lev_6\ord_com.php(538):
>   FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\paginaoctago\temp\lev_6\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271

El código es el siguiente:

```
<body>
    <script src="js/main.js">
    </script> 
<script src="consultas.js">

</script>
    <script src="funciones_de_ord_comp.js">

    </script>


<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'¡Hola, Mundo!');
$pdf->Output();

?>
</body>
```

Comment: No puede haber nada que salga por pantalla, un `echo`, un `print`, un `die`... código HTML... ni siquiera un espacio en blanco en el código PHP antes de la salida del PDF. Esa es la causa del error. Si [editas tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/168546/edit) poniendo el código que  genera el PDF entonces podremos revisarla y ayudarte mejor.

Comment: la libreria de fpdf esta obsoleta le sugiero que utilizer esta libreria se llama **TCPDF** , es mucho mas facil y mas rapido https://tcpdf.org/

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La solucion** fue **quitar** todos las **salidas visuales HTML** creando un archivo PHP independiente solo para mastrar el PDF

```
<?php
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'¡Hola, Mundo!');
    $pdf->Output();

    ?>
```

Para **guardar** sin de mostrarlo se puede utilizar **colocando** los **parametros** del nombre del archivo **en** el **output**

```
$pdf->output("nombre_archivo.pdf","F")
```

---

Si se desea se pueden utilizar variables como por ejemplo

```
$filename = "nombre_del_archivo.pdf";
output($filename,"F");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
saludos a lo mejor el tema sea viejo pero no he podido resolver el problema que tengo con una ficha y local me la carga todo bien me hace las consultas sal perfecto pero al subirla al servidor no muestra nada la e obligado a mostrar el error, si me pueden ayudar y orientar es primera vez que trabajo con esta librería, he leído en algunos foros que ya está obsoleta, pero me parece que es la que tiene menos peso en cuanto a todos los archivos que requiere para generar el pdf, de igual forma si conocen alguna que no sea tan complicada, probé que tcpdf y me dio muchos errores aparte requiere casi 14 mb de librería, probé html2pdf y tampoco me gusto el resultado he leído sobre mpfd pero aun no la pruebo. y sale lo siguiente:

    Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: error FPDF: No page has been added yet in /home/public_html/demo/fpdf/fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/demo/fpdf/fpdf.php(1447): FPDF->Error('No page has bee...') #1 /home/public_html/demo/fpdf/fpdf.php(924): FPDF->_out('q 113.43 0 0 14...') #2 /home/public_html/demo/Detalleim.php(113): FPDF->Image('img/cabecera/ba...', 17, 5, 40.014769230769) #3 {main} thrown in /home/public_html/demo/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 271

el codigo no lo muestra muy bien lo subi el archivo a drive lo pueden bajar alli. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S5ghAKLXT_12ynJiCzdC1tk4-ShgP9SF/view?usp=sharing
```